# Spotfire - Cross Table

Tags: spotfire

[image]I have a case where I have 2 rows which has the same data. They look as duplicates but actually they are not.

Now I wanted them to show up in Cross table which means I need to have my two records present in the viz. In my value axis I have unique concatenate function used.

Do we have any way to show up those two records in cross table?

This can be achieved in a data table but just wanted to know if this can be achieved through a Cross Table.

Thank you beforehand for the clarification!

Comment: I need some clarification myself. if the two rows have the same data, how are they not duplicates? can you please provide samples?

Comment: Hi Niko, Thanks for looking into it. They may be duplicates but they should be available in the report. Now is it possible to show both the records in Cross table. Attaching an example for your reference. 
Note: Cell values has Unique Concatenate aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, I would like to point out that both records are technically in your cross table, you just can't distinguish between them.  If you do a Count(), which is a Row Count, it will match the number of records in your detail table.

Assuming you actually DO want to be distinguishing between your identical records in the Cross table, this **CAN** be done, though I can't think of a good example where it *should* be.  A cross table is meant to be showing you aggregations, rather than individual rows of data, and having so many columns across the top feels cluttered and odd.

Disclaimer aside, what you need to do is add a calculated column giving you a RowNumber.  The Expression for this will be similar to one of the following:

1:
Rank("IrrelevantString","ties.method=first")

2: Rank("IrrelevantString","ties.method=first",[Country],[Number],[Name])

The first method above will give each row a different value, essentially adding an identity column to your data set.  This gives you something like this

```
Country   Number  Name     Rule    RN
Spain     42      Voltes   69     1
Spain     42      Voltes   69     2
Spain     42      Voltes   70     3
France    42      Voltes   69     4
France    42      Voltes   69     5
Spain     41      Voltes   69     6
Spain     42      XXX      69     7
```

The second method will allow you to see whether you are looking at a unique row or a duplicate; if you are familiar with SQL, this is your "partition by" segment.  If you're not familiar, what it's essentially doing is splitting the data by the columns listed, and giving a row number to everything in that data set.

So if you had

```
Country   Number  Name     Rule
Spain     42      Voltes   69
Spain     42      Voltes   69
Spain     42      Voltes   70
France    42      Voltes   69
France    42      Voltes   69
Spain     41      Voltes   69
Spain     42      XXX      69
```

Your RowNumber Column would be

```
Country   Number  Name     Rule   RN
Spain     42      Voltes   69     1
Spain     42      Voltes   69     2
Spain     42      Voltes   70     3
France    42      Voltes   69     1
France    42      Voltes   69     2 
Spain     41      Voltes   69     1
Spain     42      XXX      69     1
```

This RowNumber can then be added as a Column/Row grouping in your Cross Table and VOILA, for whatever bizarre reason, you are showing every distinct row in your data set separately.

Comment: "A cross table is meant to be showing you aggregations, rather than individual rows of data, and having so many columns across the top feels cluttered and odd." -- absolutely true. @san, please consider what you're trying to display and make sure this is the appropriate visualization type for your purposes